# Camera Preview Issue?

Tags: android

In my Application the camera preview is working properly in both in potrait and in landscape mode .No crashes are occuring.but the users are complainting that the crashes are occuring when they are using the same. what is the problem with this? please anyone help me to solve this issue

Comment: On any particular device(s)? Have you managed to get a log from any users?

Comment: ok i will try. users are repoting that the images are crashed in potrait mode.they are getting a Runtime Exception

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are requesting a supported camera preview resolution.

See [`Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes()) for details on how to query for supported resolutions and request a supported resolution with `Camera.Parameters.setPreviewSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to disable restarting camera on rotation by fixing layout in your activity, like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the device is unable to set preview parameters. 
You can use following code for setting preview parameters which will work in any device.

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {



if (isPreviewRunning) {
    camera.stopPreview();
}
try{
Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
if(p!=null){
List<Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, w, h);
p.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
camera.setParameters(p);

camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);;
camera.startPreview();

}
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block


    e.printStackTrace();
}

isPreviewRunning = true;
}
private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
if (sizes == null) return null;

Size optimalSize = null;
double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

int targetHeight = h;

// Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
for (Size size : sizes) {
double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
optimalSize = size;
minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
}
}

// Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
if (optimalSize == null) {
minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for (Size size : sizes) {
if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
optimalSize = size;
minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
}
}
}
return optimalSize;
```

}

try this.